# jquery .animate() is repeating over and over on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

Hi I have a 'back to top' button which fades in and animates once the browser is scrolled certain distance. The problem is every time the browser is scolled it repeats the .animate() again and again. Any ideas how to stop the animation once it has happened once? Cheers

Here is the code:

```
  $('.up_arrow').hide();

  // fade in up arrow 
  $(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.up_arrow').fadeIn(2000, 'swing')

        .animate ({
           opacity: 1,
           left: '+=30'
        },
        {
           duration: '2000',
           easing: 'swing',
           queue: false
        }           
        );

        } else {
        $('.up_arrow').fadeOut(2000, 'swing');
        }
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function () {
    var stop = false;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100 && stop == false) {
            $('.up_arrow').fadeIn(2000, 'swing')
                .animate({
                opacity: 1,
                left: '+=30'
            }, {
                duration: '2000',
                easing: 'swing',
                queue: false
            });
            stop = true;
        } else {
            $('.up_arrow').fadeOut(2000, 'swing');
            stop = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: From my tests the "stop == false" statement should be an if inside the "scrollTop > 100" if statement. Otherwise you would scroll to 120 and be false, it would go in and set stop to true then the immediate next frame would be 121 and true and sett stop back to false and then would immediately be ready to animate again on the next frame at 122. Confusing I know.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the stop() method should work here and would probably be the best practice.

e.g.

```
$('.up_arrow').stop().fadeOut(2000, 'swing');
```

I've only used it with animate() alone but it should do the trick.